# ASP.Net MVC 4 How to pass model property into view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For the first here an example of my code.
Property in model:

```
[Display(Name = "My Name for Quantity")]
public int Quantity { get; set; }
```

Then i send some data from controller to view and in view i use:

```
Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
```

From this one on above i get "My Name for Quantity".

The question is. How to get original property name(Quantity) and property type(int)?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to write a method like this:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
{
    return (propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
}
```

To use it, you'd write something like this:

```
var propertyName = GetPropertyName(
    () => model.Quantity); // returns "Quantity"
```